# Elisp and Perl function to automatically start pdb Python session in Emacs... possible?

Tags: perl, emacs, lisp

Here's kind of a crazy idea... I want to start the python debugger from Perl using Emacs Lisp using the Python command line that is used to invoke it from Perl.

Here's the code below, but it doesn't seem to work - but it's been years since I used Emacs.   Then the next hurdle is how to use pdb in Emacs.  Anyways, I was only interested in doing this because I was hoping pdb in Emacs would show the line of execution in the source buffer as I step through the code.
Maybe there's a better way to invoke a Python debugger from a Perl script with all the commmand line arguments for the Python script?

Elisp in question

```lisp
(progn
    ;; Switch to Messages Buffer
    (with-current-buffer "*Messages*" (erase-buffer))
    (switch-to-buffer "*Messages*")
        
    (message "Opening file: %s" "$script")
    (find-file "$script")
    (message "running pdb with script: %s and args: %s"
           "$script", "$argcat")
    (pdb (concat "pdb $script $argcat"))
)
```

Here's the Perl code the Elisp is embedded in:

```perl
sub x1_python_debugger {
    my @args = @_;
    
    # Run python script in emacs debugger...  
    #
    # USAGE:   x1_python_debugger("my_script.py", "arg1", "arg2");
    
    if (scalar(@args) == 1) {
       @args = split(/\s+/, $args[0]);
    }
    
    print "\nX1: @args\n";       
    
    my $script = shift(@args);
    my $argcat = join(' ', @args);
    
    
    # Convert to a fullpath
    my $script = ez_search_path($script);
    if (!defined($script)) {
        die("ERROR: x1_python_debugger(): could not locate in ENV{PATH}: $script\n");
    }
    
    my $lisp_program = qq{
        (progn
        ;; Switch to Messages Buffer
        (with-current-buffer "*Messages*" (erase-buffer))
        (switch-to-buffer "*Messages*")
        
            (message "Opening file: %s" "$script")
            (find-file "$script")
            (message "running pdb with script: %s and args: %s" "$script", "$argcat")
            (pdb (concat "pdb $script $argcat"))
    )
    };
    
#    my $command = qq{emacs -nw -q --eval "$lisp_program"};
    
    my $command = qq{emacs -q --eval "$lisp_program"};
    print "CMD: $command\n";
    my $rc = system($command) / 256;
    if ($rc) {
        die("cannot start python debugger in emacs\n");
    }
    
}
```

```perl
# Locate executable in the path and return fullpath
#    returns undef if not found
sub ez_search_path {
   my ($xfile, $opt_xrequired) = @_;
   
   # xrequired parameter is optional
   $opt_xrequired = 0 if (!defined($opt_xrequired));
   my $opt_fullpath  = 1;
   
   # Provided path to $xfile, by pass path search
   if ($xfile =~ m{/} || -f $xfile) {
       return $opt_fullpath ? abs_path($xfile) : $xfile;
   }
   
   # Locate xfile in $ENV{PATH}
   for my $dir (split /:/, $ENV{PATH}) {
       my $path = File::Spec->catfile($dir, $xfile);
       if (-f $path) {
           if (!$opt_xrequired || -x $path) {
               return $opt_fullpath ? abs_path($path) : $path;
       }
       }
   }
   return undef;
}
```

Comment: Why the detour via Perl?

Comment: because i'm using perl to glue together various commands one of which is a python script with some command line arguments... and its kind of awkward to start the python debugger outside of this perl code on the command prompt.

Comment: one thought is:  (pdb (concat "pdb $script $argcat"))  should be:   (pdb (concat "python -m pdb $script $argcat")) ??

Comment: My reason for asking is primarily that mixing three languages in your question reduces the audience significantly. Ideally, replacing the Perl hack with an Elisp hack would perhaps even solve your problem; but more realistically, please [edit] to explain in more detail what the Perl code does and why.

Answer (score 0):

I got this example to work in bash... perl code should follow in a similar manner.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# File: pymacs
# 5/26/2023
#----------------------------------------------------

script_name=$(basename $0)

if (( $# == 0 )); then
    echo ""
    echo "USAGE:"
    echo "    $script_name <python_script> [args...]"
    echo "PURPOSE:"
    echo "  start python script in emacs python debugger mode";
    echo ""
    exit 1
fi

args="$@"
emacs -nw -q --eval "(pdb \"python -m pdb $args\" )"
# -nw    : run emacs in terminal mode
# -q     : starts Emacs with minimal initializations
# --eval : evaluates the provided ELisp expression.
```